# C# SharpDX - Rendering freezes while interacting with UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, directx

I have an app where I use SharpDX to render models, and also a simple UI to interact with said models. The problem is that everytime I interact with the UI, the SDX rendering just stops.

I made a simple app and recorded a gif to show the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgnB.gif

I made the loop exactly as the sample app they provide, and also using "Application.DoEvents()". For me, the logical solution would be using multithreading. But I readed somewhere to avoid multithreading on DX as much as possible, and it also have a performance penalty. So what is the best solution to this issue?

**Edit:** Just tried to run DX stuff on a separated thread. As expected, the rendering doesn't freeze if I interact with the UI, but I can now see why it isn't recommended. First, performance dropped from 60 to 30 fps, and it also seems to crash randomly. So this isn't a solution.